# SSH Tunneling from Windows to Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, tunnel

My question is for my girlfriend basicly.... She works at a mall and doesn't do much so she likes to get on myspace and facebook as most girls do and yahoo to check her email. Well she uses her laptop to connect to a wireless network that doesn't allow it.... so I did some research and got putty and connected to my linux box I have here at home and it worked somewhat. My problem is it only views my webpages I have created here on this box it won't go outside of the linux host. I did it like this in putty... port is 1000 and hostname:80 is what I got outa my research then connected after seting up the tunnel bam worked for all webpages on my box but when she puts in www.myspace.com it redirects to my index.php in my var/www and won't travel outside that as I said.. Any help would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out works great just had to install squid and change ports on my Linux box and tunnels fine now :D